# Setup a static IP allocated to dedicated server

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

So, I bought a new IP for my dedicated server from a reseller of Psychz Networks. This is the only information they gave me:

```
IP: 104.206.231.109
Gateway: 104.206.231.1
Netmask: 255.255.255.128
```

So, I've set my Interfaces file up like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
address 104.206.231.109
netmask 255.255.255.128
gateway 104.206.231.1
```

... annnd I ran

```
 services networking restart
```

and got:

```
 stop: Job failed while stopping
 start: Job is already running: networking
```

Oh, and my resolv.conf:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search dal.us.mpgs.system
```

Oh, and here's `ifconfig`

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:27306645 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27306645 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2978675193 (2.9 GB)  TX bytes:2978675193 (2.9 GB)

p4p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:76:c3:ba
          inet addr:104.206.231.47  Bcast:104.206.231.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe76:c3ba/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18388696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13534048 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6282692826 (6.2 GB)  TX bytes:2823775361 (2.8 GB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fb900000-fb920000
```

How can I fix this? I've got it all setup correctly as far as I can see.

Comment: What is your ethernet interface? `ifconfig` You are starting p4p1 automatically, but not eth0; why? Once I find out more, I will propose an answer.

Comment: chili555: I have no idea, I've only added the last section onto it. I'm not very good with networking. (added ifconfig, btw)

Answer (score 1):

According to your `ifconfig`, your relevant interface is *p4p1*. I suggest you amend your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to read:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet static
address 104.206.231.109
netmask 255.255.255.128
gateway 104.206.231.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 104.206.231.1
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown p4p1 && sudo ifup p4p1
```

Did you get the desired address?

```
ifconfig
```

Can you reach the internet?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get the desired address and ping returns, you're all set.

Comment: That entirely broke my server machine. I can't connect anymore.

Comment: Wait, no. The new IP works but the old one doesn't...

Comment: Maybe I should be clarifying, I have two IPs, 104.206.231.47 and 104.206.231.109. Now the second one is only working with the config you provided.

Comment: To which interface is x.47 attached if not p4p1? Did you show us all of `ifconfig`?

Comment: Dude, I don't know :(. And yes, I did.

Comment: If you only have one ethernet interface, namely p4p1, how and why are you able to use two different addresses? Do you do this in Windows? How? Are there two ethernet ports on the back of the server hardware?

Comment: I got no idea. Stop asking me how please, it's not helping me at all. I just need help and my hosting provider WONT give  me it.

Comment: I have no idea how to use two addresses with one ethernet port. I have no other suggestions. Sorry.